# On the possibility of steel nails as EMI filters

Tags: emi-filtering

I live in a place where ferrite beads for EMI suppression are hard to get.
I thought steel had a very high iron loss, especially at high frequencies.
So is it possible at least theoretically to use hard steel nails to attenuate high frequency noise in, say, power supplies?

Comment: I don't know. And google didn't grab up anything for a chart on the relative impedance versus frequency of steel nails, either. Since I haven't tried it, I'll leave it to those who are far more prone to using steel nails instead of ferrite beads in their projects than I've been.

Comment: So you live in a place where ferrite beads are hard to get, but power supplies that produce high frequency EMI aren't?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, SMPS modules available here are all very noisy.

Comment: Most SMPS modules have EMI suppression built in. If it's not enough then perhaps you could scavenge parts from surplus units? (I live in a place where components of all types are easy to get, but I still dismantle old equipment for parts rather than just throw it all away).

Comment: Yes, "most". But I have not seen one in modules you can buy from component shops. Here only chinese ones are available. Of course SMPS in commercial and branded equipments do have it. But dismantling costly appliances does not make any sense and that is why I thought of steel nails.

Comment: Certainly it's possible, but (when I had EMI testing needs) the repeatability requirements meant we couldn't use such things in a product.  One can also tie a wire in a simple knot to form an inductor.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Most 'well built' modules, yes. There's still enough crap on the market.

Comment: Scavenge old cables to computer monitors or TVs? They pretty much all come with a ferrite.

Comment: a long PCB trace or wire with caps at either end can make enough extra difference to pass conducted EMI often. Also, for the lower frequencies of noise, just use a small shielded power inductor, assuming you can get them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I thought steel has a very high iron loss especially at high
>   frequencies. So is it possible at least theoretically to use hard
>   steel nails to attenuate high frequency noise in say power supplies?

No, not really. A ferrite bead (for instance) relies on the outer ferrite material (not the through-going wire) being both a poor electrical conductor at low frequencies but, at high frequencies, becoming a lossy capacitor and capable of turning EMI into heat. Here are a few examples from Murata: -

[image]

As you should be able to see, FBs are designed to target a specific range of frequencies and, different values in the same model range can be chosen to give better attenuation at certain parts of the spectrum whilst maintaining reasonably low losses for signals that should not be significantly attenuated.

> I live in a place where ferrite beads for emi suppression is hard to
>   get

A nail doesn't have one of the vital characteristics of ferrite that make it very useful as an attenuator namely; that it acts as a lossy capacitor as frequency gets higher and therefore resonates with the parallel inductance of the through-going wire.

There is a good document [from Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ferrite-beads-demystified.html) that explains things in more detail and that document shows the developed model for a Tyco Electronics BMB2A1000LN2: -

[image]

R1 and C1 represent the lossy dielectric of the ferrite material and you just won't get that with a regular piece of iron or a nail. In case anyone notices the typo in the ADI picture above (L1 = 1.208 uF) should read 1.208 uH thus producing a peak resonance at around 112 MHz.

Comment: Did you mean lossy resistor? Because in the link you provided it says, "It becomes resistive over its intended frequency range and dissipates the noise energy in the form of heat." and "To reduce high frequency noise, the bead must be in the resistive region; this is especially desirable for electromagnetic interference (EMI) filtering applications. The component acts like a resistor, which impedes the high frequency noise and dissipates it as heat."

Comment: @ASWINVENU no, because a lossy resistor is just a resistor. I meant a lossy capacitor and that can be modeled as a capacitor in parallel with a resistor; that resistor representing the dielectric losses.

Comment: But the web page does not say anything about that. It does say about the resonance though."A ferrite bead can be modeled as a simplified circuit consisting of resistors, an inductor, and a capacitor, as shown in Figure 1a. RDC corresponds to the dc resistance of the bead. CPAR, LBEAD, and RAC are (respectively) the parasitic capacitance, the bead inductance, and the ac resistance (ac core losses) associated with the bead."

Comment: Early on it says: *ac resistance (ac core losses) associated with the bead* and this is the heart of what I'm talking about. The ferrite core is basically non-conducting for DC because you can regard the ferrite as tiny insulated islands of conductivity that possess capacitance to each other so, as frequency rises, these islands of conductivity get connected capacitively. But they are not perfect conductors and have loss hence, the combined effect is capacitance and resistance in parallel/series arrangements that can be bulk modeled as a single capacitor in parallel with a resistor.

Comment: Ok now it's clear thanks. And one more thing, can I use the toroids on a computer motherboard for emi filtering?

Comment: @ASWINVENU There's a good chance those toroid cores are made of ferrite or similar, so it's worth a shot. But not all of those are equal or made for the same purpose, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: @ASWINVENU the toroids used in some switching supplies are likely to be common-mode filter chokes so using them as they are electrically intended is a decent idea but, you will need grounding capacitors to make them effective. On the other hand, re-purposing the ferrite is likely not to be as effective as you think at frequencies where FBs are effective. FBs start to become effective above 10 MHz and, the ferrite in toroids (unless very specifically chosen) will not be good at suppressing EMI above 10 MHz (just like many FBs are not good at suppressing EMI above 100 MHz). Horses for courses.

Comment: @ASWINVENU if you are done with this question and answer you should choose an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 12):

People used to make lossy inductors (chokes) by scramble-winding 100 turns around a 100 ohm resistor; have the choke and resistor in parallel.

The scramble/random winding was to minimize the coherent capacitance between layers of the wire, thus reducing risk of any resonances.

If this RFC Radio Frequency Choke were in the plate of a Class C amplifier, you'd probably use a 2_watt 1,000 ohm AllenBradley resistor; the large resistor was needed for surviving the high voltage.

Read some construction articles in old ARRL (ham) manuals. Or QST magazines.

Comment: Thos were the days :-) +1

Answer (score 10):

The full theory here is very messy. You have skin effect and hysteresis loss in play. So, I thought I'd do an experiment. I close-wound a coil of #32 magnet wire on a 10D 3" galvanized steel nail. Here's the coil:

[image]

Note that the ruler is centimeters.

I measured the attenuation with the coil placed in series between a sinusoidal function generator and a scope with a 50 ohm terminator across its input. From that, I calculated the impedance versus frequency:

[image]

Not so different from a ferrite choke.

Edit:

For more detail, I took more measurements with a tightened-up test setup. I give raw measurements for your computational enjoyment. Input voltage was 1V RMS sine waves: I readjusted the function generator output for each frequency. The time delay through the setup with the coil shorted was 29 ns, measured with a square wave. I have not corrected the delay below for this.

- MHz  Volts Delay(ns)
- 1.0 0.36 100
- 1.4 0.34 71
- 2.0 0.28 59
- 2.8 0.25 48
- 4.0 0.21 38
- 5.6 0.19 32
- 8.0 0.16 28
- 11.0 0.15 24
- 16.0 0.16 21
- 22.0 0.22 20

The "resonance" is extremely broad.

Comment: Thanks for doing an experiment. So you are saying it is possible to use steel nails?

Comment: Possible? Sure. May take some experimentation to get it to work. A different nail might give a different result.

Comment: Ok, my theory was that iron losses are contributing towards the attenuation. Is that correct? or is there another explanation?

Comment: As I said, the theory is difficult. There's some combination of ohmic loss (eddy currents), and magnetic hysteresis loss going on here, but I have no calculation.

Comment: No, I'm just curious. In the first answer someone said something about ferrite acting as a lossy capacitor. I'm wondering how is that. Also someone said the nail acting as shorted transformer.

Comment: 6 points isn't enough to tell the Q (and loss) of the inductor. Can you test at some intermediate frequencies (eg. 2,3,4,5MHz etc.) to determine the peak response? Also, what do you get if the same coil is wound on an inert core? (sorry for asking, I would do it myself but I don't have the equipment).

Comment: I agree with @BruceAbbott, there is a reasonable possibility that the self capacitance of the winding is producing a self resonant frequency and also, plotting the impedance doesn't really tell you what the losses are. Having 100 ohm impedance at maybe 1000 kHz isn't what I'd call something that is broadly useful. You have basically made an inductor with a low self resonant frequency.

Comment: It might be interesting to add a secondary winding with a resistor (100 ohm?) across it. I think that would give you true loss at higher frequencies.

Comment: @Andy aka The slope and phase delay tell us about the dissipation. Slope is way below what you'd expect from an LR low pass, and the maximum phase delay (after accounting for cable delays) is only 25 degrees (at 1 MHz). So, it's a lousy inductor, very lossy, like the ferrite EMI inductors.

Comment: I don't doubt that it's lossy, I am just trying to characterize it. Do you know what the resonant frequency is? What gauge is the wire (and/or what is the resistance of the coil?).

Comment: @Bruce Abbot As I said above, it's #32 magnet wire. DC resistance is ~5 Ω.

Comment: @Bruce Abbot See edit. Have fun.

Answer (score 5):

As Andy explained, steel won't work. Besides, its magnetic permeability gets lower as frequency increases, and if you wind an inductor over a nail, then the nail which is conductive will make your inductor act as a transformer with a shorted turn secondary* and the inductor will be rather useless.

You can get ferrite cores for free on old cables though.

[image]

*: Inductors with solid conductive cores (like a nail) are a bad idea. The AC magnetic field will induce [eddy currents](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-minimize-the-effect-of-an-eddy-current-in-an-inductor) into the core, which turns the inductor into a transformer. The primary of this transformer is the inductor, and the secondary is the core itself which is the same as a secondary coil with a single shorted turn.

[image]

This increases losses (not a problem here) but it also makes the inductor less effective... not what you want for filtering.

Comment: As a transformer?? I think not. I have done experiments using only the primary of transformer making it behave exactly like an inductor. I believe you are talking about eddy current losses.

Comment: Yeah, eddy currents are what happens when the core is conductive and becomes the secondary of the transformer... I added some explanations in the answer.

Comment: Yeah that is the point. The ferrite dissipates the EMI as heat in the form of iron loss.

Answer (score 1):

No less a guru than Tom Rauch, W8JI himself debunked the idea of using a solid steel core in place of ferrite.

From https://www.w8ji.com/steel_wool_balun.htm:

> Bolt baluns, steel wool balun cores, and other solid iron or steel or laminated cores are a HOAX. They are not baluns at all. The text below explains why they are hoaxes.
>
> A problem arises when magnetic fields are changing level. A time-varying magnetic field will generate currents in any closed conductor path, even iron. This current is called an "eddy current". The amount of current depends on the size of the iron particle(s) forming the conductor and the change rate of the magnetic field. The larger the particles, the larger the conductor area for eddy currents become. The larger the area, the lower the frequency where eddy current start to cause problems.
>
> Eddy currents generate their own opposing magnetic field to the incident field exciting the core. If the iron has large enough cross section eddy currents and the resulting counter MMF from the eddy currents will push the magnetic fields back out of the core. With increasing frequency, a given size iron particle has a frequency where inductance starts to decrease. This effect is from the "shorted turn" generating opposing flux. As frequency increases further, inductance decreases. At some frequency the core is no longer able to support the field, and because of eddy currents, actually reduces inductance.
>
> For example, inserting a solid iron slug inside a small RF coil shows a behavior almost identical to using brass or aluminum slugs. Inserting a solid slug of iron might increases the magnetic field concentration and inductance near direct current frequencies, but at some higher frequency eddy currents and the inability of the core to follow field changes cause the flux concentration to decrease.....eventually reaching zero. At some frequency, the counter MMF takes over. Inductance is actually reduced by the core. ...

I have performed this very same test here with iron, brass, and aluminum cores with the same results. I used an MFJ-259B, while Tom used the expensive test equipment in his lab.

> ... Let's stop this myth about steel wool and steel bolt baluns. Audio core materials are laminated or powdered for good reason. RF cores are small insulated particles packed together for a reason. A solid material does not behave like a smaller cross section material.

---

The same principles for a good EMI choke also apply here. Sure, a balun passes RF on the center conductor and the inside of the shield. However, its principal function is *to choke off any common-mode current on the outside of the shield*.

Also, any unwanted energy that dissipates in an EMI choke is going to be in the form of *heat*. An EMI filter choke needs to have a high resistance at RF if it is not going to pass RF, same as a balun.

Comment: I believe the OP isn't talking about a balun, but a lossy EMI choke. A balun's job is to transmit electromagnetic energy between its ports. An EMI choke's job is to dissipate unwanted electromagnetic energy. A properly chosen ferrite can do either. Bulk steel cannot (although "powdered iron" in an insulating binder can).

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about lossy chokes.

Comment: Answer edited to explain further.

Comment: And your edit didn't address the issue. As my measurements above showed, the coil wound around the nail has a large RF impedance (about 50 times its DC resistance) at MHz frequencies. Unlike an inductive choke, this impedance is dominated by resistance, not reactance. Reactance reflects power, resistance absorbs some of it. This is a simple coil, intended to suppress EMI on a single wire, not a balun suppressing common mode but passing differential mode. 250 Ω is good for this, as the characteristic impedance of a wire that's not part of a transmission line will probably be of this order.